# Taking long time to call api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api2

I'm using VSTO solution and sending the mail item data to API. I tried to send the image object data as binary and sending to Web API. If I tried to send an object with 25MB data it's taking 10 to 15 sec's to hit the API call.

Comment: I don't think 10 to 15 seconds is unreasonable to upload 25mb.

Comment: Thanks for reply @Crowcoder, it's not uploading. To hit the API itself it's taking 10 to 15 sec's.

Comment: @NaveenDonepudi What you mean it's not uploading? To call the API, you of course need to upload the data to the server. Also, there is nothing "available below"

Comment: Oops, I was moving the mail item in Outlook which is taking long time since it's synchronous call it's taking long time and freezing the application. Thank you all :)